# Chrome Extension - Append HTML & Run jQuery Function on Extension Click

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm in the midst of creating my first Chrome Extension (Trying)

I feel like I'm close...  But I genuinely don't know what to google to get the answers I need.  So I'm sorry if this is a silly question.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is on click of extension - Append HTML & CSS to body and run a jQuery function.  But from the looks of it, I need to call in jQuery in the manifest?  Which I think I've done and it's still not working.

My Code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Title",
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Hover Title",
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
 "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery-1.7.2.min.js", "background.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    (function ($) {
        $('body').append("Hello");
        alert("Hello");
        console.log("Hello");
    }(jQuery));

});
```

Any insight into where I'm going wrong would be massively helpful!

Thank you!!

Comment: Please please please read the [extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) and check [the samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:browseraction) (the very first example "page redder" extension is only a few lines long).

Comment: @wOxxOm So I have a question.  I've checked out the page redder.  Inside its background.js there's a console.log.  This doesn't fire, which I assume means that it's not using jQuery?

Comment: Looks like you have overlooked manifest.json of that extension and didn't read the doc page... right? :-D

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm completely lost!  I genuinely have no idea where I'm supposed to be looking, I've looked through both links but haven't read anything about jQuery?   Sorry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome [extension architecture is simple](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) but it doesn't mean one can write code without studying it.

There are two methods of injecting content scripts:

1. Unconditionally on all specified urls, in which case ["content_script"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) key is used in the manifest and the content scripts communicate with the background page via [runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage).
2. Only when some event occurs like e.g. the user clicks our toolbar icon, in which case we only need the permission to [access the active tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions).

So in the given case we'll attach the icon click handler and [inject the code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) afterwards:

- **manifest.json**:

  ```js
  {
      "name": "Title",
      "description": "Description",
      "version": "1.0",
      "browser_action": {
          "default_title": "Icon Title",
          "default_icon": "icon.png"
      },
      "background": {
          "scripts": ["background.js"]
      },
      "permissions": ["activeTab"],
      "manifest_version": 2
  }
  ```
- **background.js** (this is an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) because we didn't use `"persistent": true` in the manifest, so be advised that the [global] variables will be lost after a few seconds of inactivity; instead you should use [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) or HTML5 localStorage/sessionStorage/and so on):

  ```js
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "jquery-1.7.2.min.js"}, function(result) {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"}, function(result) {
          });
      });
  });
  ```
- **content.js** (the code [runs in a sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) so there's no need to hide global variables using [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression))

  ```js
  $('body').append("Hello");
  alert("Hello");
  console.log("Hello");
  ```

Comment: Brilliant!!

Thank you for this! :)